# c++ Permanent Offline Counter

Tags: c++, counter, transactional

I have an embedded server, which can be **unplugged any time**. Is there an elegant way to implement a **transactional c++ counter**? In the worst case it should return the previous ID.

I have an embedded server which periodically generates report files. The server does not have time or network connection, so I want to generate the report files incrementally. However, after the report files are downloaded I would like to delete the report files, while maintaining the counter:

```
report00001.txt
report00002.txt
report00003.txt
report00004.txt
// all the files have been deleted
report00005.txt
...
```

I would like to use a code like this:

```
 int last = read_current_id("counter.txt");
 last++;
 // transaction begin
 write_id("counter.txt", last);
 // transaction end
```

Comment: "I would like to use a code like this" What keeps you from doing so?

Comment: @Swordfish Presumably concerns about the atomicity of `write_id`...

Comment: Yes, the question concerns the atomicity of write_id. Write ID must delete the content of 'counter.txt'. What happens if the device is unplugged at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming your server is running some sort of unixy operating system)

You could try using the write-and-rename idiom for this.

What you do is write your new counter value to a different file, say `counter.txt~`, then [`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) the temporary file onto the regular `counter.txt`. `rename` guarantees that either the new or old version of the file will exist at any time.

You should also mount your filesystem with the [`sync`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) option so that file contents are not buffered in RAM. Note however that this will reduce performance, and may shorten lifespan of flash memory.

Comment: I like this idea, thank You. It is Linux (buildroot).